# Why do I need to decorate login_required decorator with @method_decorator

Tags: django, decorator, django-class-based-views, login-required

I am trying to understand the code for the mixins posted at [this blog post](http://brack3t.com/our-custom-mixins.html).

These mixins call the `login_required` decorator from `django.contrib.auth.decorators` within the mixins , but they do so decorated by the `method_decorator` from `django.utils.decorators`.
In the sample code below I dont understand why I need to decorate the `login_required` decorator .

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    """
    View mixin which verifies that the user has authenticated.

    NOTE:
        This should be the left-most mixin of a view.
    """
    # Why do I need to decorate login_required here
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `method_decorator` decorator says it is used to "Converts a function decorator into a method decorator" But in test code I can use my decorator even without the method_decorator.

My decorator

```
def run_eight_times(myfunc):
    def inner_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(8):
            myfunc(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner_func
```

My class which calls the above decorator directly produces the same result as if I called the decorator decorated by `method_decorator`

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
class Myclass(object):

    def __init__(self,name,favorite_dish):
        self.name = name
        self.favorite_dish = favorite_dish

    # This next line is not required
    #@method_decorator(run_eight_times)
    @run_eight_times
    def undecorated_function(self):
        print "%s likes spam in his favorite dish %s" % (self.name,self.favorite_dish)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Django's method_decorator is set up to pass the `self` argument in correctly to the decorated function. The reason this doesn't show up in the test cases you wrote above with the `run_eight_times` decorator is that the `inner_func` in `run_eight_times` blindly passes all arguments in to myfunc via `*args` and `**kwargs`. In general, this won't be the case.

To see this with your example, try the following:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

def run_eight_times(myfunc):
    def inner_func(what_he_likes, **kwargs):
        # override...
        what_he_likes = 'pizza'
        for i in range(8):
            myfunc(what_he_likes, **kwargs)
    return inner_func

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name, favorite_dish):
        self.name = name
        self.favorite_dish = favorite_dish

    # This next line required!
    @method_decorator(run_eight_times)
    #@run_eight_times
    def undecorated_function(self, what_he_likes):
        print "%s likes %s in his favorite dish %s" % (
            self.name, what_he_likes, self.favorite_dish
        )

def main():
    inst = MyClass('bob', 'burrito')
    inst.undecorated_function('hammy spam')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Specifically, Django's view decorators will return a function with a signature `(request, *args, **kwargs)`. For a class based-view, this should be `(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`. That's what `method_decorator` does - transform the first signature into the second.