# Suppress "?next=blah" behavior in django's login_required decorator

Tags: django, django-authentication

I love django's @login_required decorator, but there's one thing I can't figure out how to make it do.

If an unauthenticated user tries visits a @login_required page (e.g. "/private-stuff/"), I want to kick them back to the home page (e.g. "/home/").  But I don't want to append a "?next=" argument to the url.  In other words, I just want to redirect to "/home/", not "/home/?next=/private-stuff/".

How can I do that?  Is there a better way than just writing my own decorator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there's two ways that I can think of. First, would be the "correct" way, in the sense that you're not breaking any functionality, only adding new functionality: create your own `login_required` decorator. The problem though is that Django has *really* tucked the redirect after login functionality away, and it requires a lot of parts. The [`login_required` decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py) is really just a wrapper around the [`user_passes_test` decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py), which in turn calls the [`redirect_to_login` view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py), and it's *that* view that adds the `next` param to the querystring. In your custom decorator, you can roll all or some of this functionality straight into the decorator, but you'll need to reference all three for the necessary code.

The other, and far simpler option, is to create some middleware to remove the querystring if it's set:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class RemoveNextMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path == settings.LOGIN_URL and request.GET.has_key('next'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

And, then add the import path to that middleware to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. Remember that in the request phase, middleware is processed first to last or top-down, in other words. This should come relatively early in the request phase, but you may need to play around a bit with it to see what can and can't come before it.

The only real problem with this method is that it "breaks" the next redirect functionality, and not in a very intuitive way, if a later developer inherits your codebase along with a mandate to allow the redirect, it might be a bit flummoxing.

Comment: has_key is deprecated. use 'in' instead.

Comment: @PatrickBassut it's not deprecated, it's completely removed in Python 3. I've updated the answer to be python3 compatible. Python 2 is obsolete, I wonder why people still use it in 2017.

Answer (score 45):

Isn't it just simply as:

```
@decorators.login_required(redirect_field_name=None)
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?  This was some months ago, but I think I tried redirect_url=None and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I did try it with the current version of Django. Note that the parameter is `redirect_field_name` and not `redirect_url`.

Comment: Is that part of the standard @login_required functionality? I can't find any references to that in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: The signature is `login_required([redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None])`, so what is the question?

Comment: wouldn't it be `@login_required(redirect_field_name=None)` then? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required ... And this won't necessarily work in all places. The `@method_decorator`, for example, is designed to take `self` as an argument and can work in different scenarios... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560840/why-do-i-need-to-decorate-login-required-decorator-with-method-decorator

Comment: Works, yet I was unable to find a way of configuring this globally in the settings.py. Is there a way?

Comment: to use it in `urls.py`  urlpatterns array: `url(r'^$', login_required( IndexView.as_view(), redirect_field_name=None ) )`

Comment: You are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

```
login(request, user)
if request.POST['next']:
    return redirect(request.POST['next'])
else:
    msg = u"Welcome..."
    return render_to_response('members/welcome.html', {'msg':msg},
                                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: It's best to add some context to explain your answer, not just the bare code. That makes it more helpful not just to this questioner but to anyone who might have the same problem in future as well. See these guidelines on [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info :)