# Redirect if already logged in through Django urls?

Tags: django

Currently I use these patterns to log in and out

```
urlpatterns += patterns("",
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    (r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'logout.html'})
)
```

Inspite of having LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/' in my settings.py, Django does not send me to /profile/ if I want to access /login/ when I'm already logged in...

Can I somehow redirect in the URL patterns of the auth system? I'm reluctant to write a custom view for that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I use something like this in my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


login_forbidden =  user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_anonymous(), '/')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login_forbidden(login), name="login"),
```

Comment: +1 Worked perfectly, I prefer using my url name in case my paths change, altered the answer a bit `login_forbidden = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_anonymous(), lazy(reverse, str)('my-url-name'))`

Comment: You can get rid of the `?next` url parameter by setting `redirect_field_name=None` (See [Remove ?next](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12764484/2228912)). This parameter appears in the url after the user get redirected (e.g. if he's authenticated in this case).

Answer (score 4):

How about riding the `Django login` view?

Then add this little piece of code in that view:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
      # Redirect to profile
```

If you want to do something else in template itself for the register user:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

Comment: `is_authenticated()` is not callable. (it's boolean) this following worked for me : 
 ```if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing a decorator for such task.

Please take note that I've made it quick & dirty.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def redirect_if_logged(f=None, redirect_to_url=None):
    u"""
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is already logged in, redirecting
    to certain URL if so.
    """
    def _decorator(view_func):
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                redirect_url = redirect_to_url

                if redirect_to_url is None:
                    # URL has 'next' param?
                    redirect_url_1 = request.GET.get('next')
                    # If not, redirect to referer
                    redirect_url_2 = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
                    # If none, redirect to default redirect URL
                    redirect_url_3 = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

                    redirect_url = redirect_url_1 or redirect_url_2 or redirect_url_3

                return redirect(redirect_url, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view

    if f is None:
        return _decorator
    else:
        return _decorator(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L28-63) on Github, the default `login` view provided by `django.contrib.auth` will only use `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` if the login form is submitted via a `POST` request, and it has no `next` parameter. (The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) mention this too).

The `login` view doesn't actually do any checking of whether you're authenticated already or not - so an already-authenticated user hitting the page with a standard `GET` request will see the login form again - just the same as an unauthenticated user.

If you want different behaviour, I'd recommend writing your own login view.

Answer (score 1):

On your projects `urls.py` file (`url_patterns` list), add `redirect_authenticated_user=True` as a parameter in login path like this:

```py
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
                 template_name='blog_app/login.html', 
                 redirect_authenticated_user=True
                 ), name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this decorator

```py
def login_excluded(redirect_to):
    """ This decorator kicks authenticated users out of a view """
    def _method_wrapper(view_method):
        def _arguments_wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(redirect_to)
            return view_method(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _arguments_wrapper
    return _method_wrapper
```