# Django redirect user after login pending on their group

Tags: django, authentication, django-templates, django-authentication

I am using django's 'login view' via a form on my `login.html` page :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="controls controlsbtm">
      {{ form.password }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group-bottom">
    <div class="controls-btm">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="loginBtn" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />

    </div>
  </div>        
</form>
```

I have a custom decorator to check on certain pages if the user is part of a specific group, and if they arent I redirect them back to the login page. using :

```
@login_required

@user_passes_test(is_admin)
```

The problem is, djangos built in feature of returning to login page and successfully logging in returns you back to the previous URL. So if you login and you're not in the group you will get stuck in a loop.

I would like to have it so :

login as user in Group B

try URL that requires user in Group A

- return to login page

login as user in Group B

- return to standard home page and NOT redirect back to previous url

OR

login as user in Group A

- redirected back to previous URL

How would I go about doing this ?

**EDIT
after following Jakob's ideas i've got to a point where I can point the REDIRECT_URL to a custom view.
But in this view i need to be able to say :

what did the original URL want the user to be ?

does that match the newly login details, if so, go to that url
if not, go to home.html

im still unsure how to do this

Comment: Why dont you modify your decorator so that it takes in the user as parameter, checks the type of the user, and returns the corresponding url? Settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL allows only one value and dont put fancy logic in it (as far as a I know). Also, I do not think checking user type and redirecting, and again redirecting is a good idea. It costs bandwidth and work for server (you have to render template each time too).

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL just points to some url. You can put logic behind it as fanc as you like :). And "redirecting" is somehow a misleading term here. It is more like "Call the proper view from the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL's endpoint", all the work is done serverside.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [Settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url).

With this you could redirect to some other view where you can do the group check and redirect from there again to the proper location.

EDIT:
Setting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL will only work if you remove the next parameter. From the docs:

> The URL where requests are redirected after login when the contrib.auth.login
>   view **gets no next parameter**.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950409/suppress-next-blah-behavior-in-djangos-login-required-decorator) is a question that describes how to do it.

Overwriting contrib.auth.login might be another way to go. Let Django do the default login stuff and chack your groups afterwards. Then redirect to the proper location (via the next parameter).

**EDIT2:**

If I got you right you want some setup like the following:
always return to login page on failure.

- login as user in Group A: is_admin => True (in group) => redirect to previous page on success
- login as user in Group B: is_admin => False (not in group) => redirect to default (login-protected) page

Try this one:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='nasenb'),
    url(r'^login/', login, {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
    url(r'^adminonly/', admin_only),
    url(r'^protected/', protected_content),
    url(r'^', free_content, name='index'),
)
```

views.py

```
def is_admin(user):
    return True #or False for test purpose

# login_url='/protected/': this is the default redirect url 
# where to go if is_admin fails but the login succeeded
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_admin, login_url='/protected/', redirect_field_name=None)
def admin_only(request):
    return HttpResponse('Access granted, passed "is_admin"')

@login_required()
def protected_content(request):
    return HttpResponse('this content does''n require admin privs')
"""
this is some previous page
"""
def free_content(request):
    return HttpResponse('Some data! Free for everyone!')
```

hope this helps!

Comment: this is very promising !
@user_passes_test(is_admin,redirect_field_name=None)

worked a treat, redirected me back to the default page after login.

but im unclear how i would return to the previous page if the user has logged in under the correct group ?

Comment: hey Jakbo ive begun creating a view that is pointed to from LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
which currently is working.
How ever, I can't see how I would pass through the True/False of the user_passes_test(), and if it's true, to also pass through the NEXT url param

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def loggedin_view(request):
    usergroup = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        usergroup = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True).first()
    if usergroup == "staffGroup":
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/cmit/userDash")
    elif usergroup == "supervisorGroup":
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/cmit/supervisorDash")
    elif usergroup == "auditGroup":
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/cmit/auditDash")
    elif usergroup == "mgtGroup":
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/cmit/mgtDash")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/")
```