# How to hide the next parameter appearing to the url in Django?

Tags: python, django

When I am starting my Django project from the login page the url is showing like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/
```

But what i want only this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
```

What is the way to hide this next parameter appearing to the url?
I have set login url and login redirect urls to the settings.py:

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='home'),
    url(r'login/$',views.userLogin,name='login'),
]
```

Comment: [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950409/suppress-next-blah-behavior-in-djangos-login-required-decorator)

Comment: Any reason you actually want to do this? When you have other pages that require a login and the user goes directly to them - it doesn't make much of a user experience they have to login, go to the home page, then have to go back to where they intended to go afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is located in the [AccessMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L35) in django.contrib.auth.

If you dislike it - inherit from `LoginRequiredMixin` and overwrite `redirect_field_name` to return `''` or `None`. You  need to use this mixin afterwards for the views for which you want to enforce login.

You should have a good reason for it. Usually as already mentioned in the comments above this behavior is useful.